# How to use Kleisli arrows with monads?

Tags: haskell, monads, arrows, kleisli

In the Haskell `Control.Arrow` documentation it talks about Kleisli arrows' relationship to monads, but it is not obvious to me how to use this. I have a function which I think fits with arrows except for it involving the IO monad, so I think Kleisli arrows may help.

Take the following function which returns pairs of original and modified filenames of a directory.

```
import System.Directory
import System.FilePath

datedFiles target = do
    fns <- getDirectoryContents target
    tms <- mapM (fmap show . getModificationTime) fns
    return $ 
        zip fns $ 
        zipWith replaceBaseName fns $ 
        zipWith (++) (map takeBaseName fns) tms
```

If I had to draw it out, it would be something like this:

[image]

I think it can benefit from the use of Kleisli arrows, but I don't know how. Can anyone provide guidance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`datedFiles` can be implemented using arrows because the information flows in a "fixed pipeline", as your diagram shows.

Here's a possible implementation that does not use `map` or `zip` on lists:

```
import System.Directory
import System.FilePath
import Control.Monad.List
import Control.Arrow

datedFiles :: FilePath -> IO [(FilePath,FilePath)]
datedFiles = fmap runListT . runKleisli $
   (Kleisli $ ListT . getDirectoryContents) 
   >>>
   returnA &&& ((Kleisli $ liftIO . getModificationTime) >>^ show)
   >>^
   fst &&& (\(path,time) -> replaceBaseName path $ takeBaseName path ++ time)
```

Arguably, it is not the most intuitive implementation.

The monad for the Kleisli arrows is `ListT IO`, although the only nondeterminism is caused by `getDirectoryContents`.

Note that the last line is a pure function; the `(&&&)` for the last line is using the Arrow instance for functions.

**Edit:** The [Wrapped](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.10/docs/Control-Lens-Wrapped.html) typeclass from the `lens` package can be used to add/remove newtype wrappers a bit more succinctly. Applying it to the previous example, we end up with:

```
import Control.Lens

datedFiles :: FilePath -> IO [(FilePath,FilePath)]
datedFiles = fmap runListT . runKleisli $
   ListT . getDirectoryContents ^. wrapped 
   >>>
   returnA &&& (liftIO . getModificationTime ^. wrapped >>^ show)
   >>^
   fst &&& (\(path,time) -> replaceBaseName path $ takeBaseName path ++ time)
```

Answer (score 9):

Monads are `Functor`s from Hask, the category of Haskell types and functions, to Hask---an endofunctor. That means that some of the arrows in Hask look like `a -> m b` for some `Monad` `m`. For a particular monad `m`, the subcategory of Hask where arrows look like `a -> m b` is the Kleisli category for `m`.

We know it's a category because there's an identity arrow `return :: a -> m a` and composition `(>>>) :: (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> (a -> m c)` defined like

```
(f >>> g) a = join (g <$> f a)
```

which is why we need this to be a `Monad`---we use both `return` and `join`.

---

In Haskell, we can't just have a subcategory normally, but instead a newtype is used.

```
import Prelude hiding ((.), id)
import Control.Category

newtype Kleisli m a b = Kleisli { runKleisli :: a -> m b }

instance Monad m => Category (Kleisli m) where
  id                    = Kleisli return
  Kleisli g . Kleisli f = Kleisli (join . fmap g . f)
```

And then we can upgrade functions of type `Monad m => a -> m b` to `Kleisli m a b`s, arrows in a category, and compose them with `(.)`

```
arr :: Kleisli IO FilePath [String]
arr = Kleisli (mapM $ fmap show . getModificationTime) . Kleisli getDirectoryContents
```

---

Generally that's a bit syntactically noisy, though. The newtype is only valuable in order to use the `Category` typeclass to overload `id` and `(.)`. Instead it's more likely that you'll see `return` and `(>=>)` which are equivalent to

```
return a = runKleisli (id a)
f >=> g  = runKleisli $ Kleisli g . Kleisli f
```

Answer (score 3):

First I'd suggest you to split handling an individual file from handling the list. In your example, `timestamp` is the interesting arrow, because all others are pure functions. Nevertheless, we can make some of them into arrows to make the example more interesting. Using the [arrow notation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/users_guide/arrow-notation.html) we can rewrite computing one file name as a Kleisli arrow:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}
import Control.Arrow
import System.Directory
import System.FilePath
import System.Time

-- Get a timestamp of a file as an arrow:
timestamp :: Kleisli IO FilePath ClockTime
timestamp = Kleisli getModificationTime

-- Insert a given string in front of the extension of a file.
-- Just as an example - we'd rather use a simple `let` instead of making it
-- an arrow.
append :: (Monad m) => Kleisli m (FilePath, String) FilePath
append = arr $ \(fn, suffix) ->
                let (base, ext) = splitExtension fn
                in base ++ suffix ++ ext

-- Given a directory, receive the name of a file as an arrow input
-- and produce the new file name. (We could also receive `dir`
-- as an input, if we wanted.)
datedArrow :: FilePath -> Kleisli IO FilePath (FilePath, FilePath)
datedArrow dir = proc fn -> do
                    ts <- timestamp -< replaceDirectory fn dir
                    fn' <- append -< (fn, show ts)
                    returnA -< (fn, fn')

datedFiles' :: FilePath -> IO [(FilePath, FilePath)]
datedFiles' target = do
                fns <- getDirectoryContents target
                mapM (runKleisli $ datedArrow target) fns
```

Answer (score 1):

Let remember main function from Monad:

```
(>>=) :: (a -> m b) -> m a  -> m b
```

and now let's look at `Kleisli`

```
newtype Kleisli m a b = Kleisli { runKleisli :: a -> m b }
```

where `Kleisli` is a wrapper and `runKleisli` - unwrapper from the newtype.

What is in common? `a -> m b` part

And let's look at instance declaration:

```
instance Monad m => Arrow (Kleisli m) where ...
```

we see, how to make `Monad` part of `Arrow`